# Template files for bioattributes and meta-data

Tags: ngs, fastq, genbank, sequence

I am in process of submiting my FASTQ files to the SRA database. I am a little confused about how to fill the biosample attributes and SRA metadata.

I would really appreciate if you anyone could share example templates or help with the given database fields.

Thank you

Comment: Hi @Riya this is certainly a good question for the site, but could you explain where you have got to so far? Screenshots would be beneficial.